# Block external storage for a user account

Tags: mac, network, security, storage

I am doing a proposal for new network where the Macs will be networked, OS X Mavericks + server app

Is there any solution to disable external storage USB/Thunderbolt/Firewire/CD/ Bluetooth? Preferably for a user account.

The point is if the company cannot control external storage then all the Firewalls and other security measures will be rendered useless.

Surprisingly even commercial vendors providing employee monitor software that will send reports of what data has been copied do not have an option to block this copying before it happens.

Comment: Surprisingly this option is not available in the Parent Control settings. What a pity !

Comment: This will also highly motivate any serious company!

Comment: Relevant: http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/58596/24324

Comment: @SaaruLindestøkke unfortunately it doesn't look like that works with on anything newer than Mountain Lion