# Connect iPhone to Mac Without Charging

Tags: iphone, mac

I am developing iOS apps and I hate, that always when I connect my iPhone to my Mac to install and test an app, the iPhone gets charged. Is there any possibility to connect my iPhone to my Mac without charging the phone?

My Environment:
-  iPhone 4S (No Jailbreak)
-  MacBook Air3,2 (Late 2010)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some Googling around, I don't believe this is possible.

Though you can disable USB ports [by unloading kexts](http://www.techkaki.com/2009/08/how-to-enable-disable-usb-ports-storage-device-access-in-mac-os-x/), *this would disable USB port functionality altogether*: it would neither supply power nor read any USB connected input device (it may still supply power, but definitely would not recognize any input).

An alternative option would be to purchase an AC powered USB hub [(for example)](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=0J2-0031-00001&cm_re=powered_usb_hub-_-0J2-0031-00001-_-Product) to reduce the power being drawn from your built in USB port when a device is connected to the hub (and hub is connected directly to AC + your machine). That way, though 500 mAh would still be allocated to the port, the iPhone would be drawing power from the AC connection. Thus, you could still connect the phone to your machine and have it recognizable via the hub without drawing power exclusively from the machine's USB port.

Related:

[Disable Specific USB Ports / Restrict Data Transfer from USB Ports](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/58596/disable-specific-usb-ports-restrict-data-transfer-from-usb-ports)

Answer (score 1):

iPhone WiFi Sync is exactly what you are looking for. I've been using it with my iPhone 4 just fine. It is noticeably slower though for large transfers.

Here is Apple's KB article

http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1386

Comment: iTunes WiFi Sync is NOT what I am looking for, I want to install and debug applications on my iPhone (via Xcode/AppCode). To do this, Xcode NEEDS the iOS device connected via a cable.

Answer (score 0):

ref: [How do you perform wireless debugging in Xcode 9 with iOS 11, Apple TV 4K, etc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44382841/how-do-you-perform-wireless-debugging-in-xcode-9-with-ios-11-apple-tv-4k-etc)
ref: [Sync content between your Mac and iPhone or iPad over Wi-Fi](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/wi-fi-syncing-mchlada1d602/mac)
ref: [Not able to "connect via network" for debugging](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/89040) (@eskimo)

Yeah, that can be a bit persnickety. Here’s what I did to get it to show up:

1. I turned off Wi-Fi on my device, just to be sure it wasn’t being
   seen on the network.
2. I connected it via USB.
3. In Xcode’s Devices window, I selected the device on the left.
4. I enabled Connect via Network on the right.
5. I disconnected the USB; the device moved to the Disconnected
   section.
6. I control clicked on the device and Connect via IP Address shows up
   in the menu.