# Disable USB C on MacBook Pro 2018

Tags: usb, security

Is there a way to disable USB C ports on my MacBook Pro 2018 for anything except charging ?

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/58596/disable-specific-usb-ports-restrict-data-transfer-from-usb-ports

Comment: Looks like that one doesn't work any more @Nimesh Neema, too bad...