# Block External Devices

Tags: external-disk

In macOS Big Sur, is there a native way to block reading and writing from external disks and USB flash drives?

Are there any third-party software apps which can perform this block?

Comment: You want to prevent any external device from been mounted on your Mac, in other words?

Comment: This post might help: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/58596/disable-specific-usb-ports-restrict-data-transfer-from-usb-ports